# jQuery validation onfocusout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have enabled jQuery validation option as follows in an MVC application.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusin: false
});
```

That means the validation will happen on focus out.
I am facing an issue here in the following scenario.

1. The user have entered an invalid data and submitted the form (Validation error will be displayed)
2. The user corrected the data and clicked the submit button without moving the focus from the current textbox. In this step, the submit will not work and only validation error cleared off. What I needed here is to submit the form if the data is correct.

I have created a jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/15/
Plase share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `onfocusin:`.  Did you mean `onfocusout:`?

You also have not used either of those in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/15/):

```
    debug: false,
    focusInvalid: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
```

Is this what you want?

```
    debug: false,
    focusInvalid: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    onfocusout: false,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/24/

[Click here to see documentation that describes each `.validate()` option in great detail](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Of course, [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/15/), seems to be working fine for me.  I'm getting "success" on `submit` without moving my cursor away from the input.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.  The desired behavior you describe is how almost everyone expects this validation to work, and it just happens to be how it works by default.

Even if you have an error with `onfocusout` set to `false`, you can still submit the form (after correcting error) without moving your cursor away because the plugin's built-in submit handler automatically checks the form's validity again.

http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/25/